# Delta Table logs during Merge-Update operation

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake, delta

Went through the doc (https://www.databricks.com/blog/2019/08/21/diving-into-delta-lake-unpacking-the-transaction-log.html). While this discusses the transaction log in Delta Lake and provides insights into add/remove operations, it does not explicitly cover the details of how Delta tables manage logs and data files during a merge/update operation.

For instance, lets say there are 2 runs.

- In run_1, two records of data are written with the corresponding _delta_log file named as 00000.json and data file file_1.parquet. It is understood that the delta log file includes an add operation pointing to the file_1.parquet data file.
- Subsequently, in run_2, two records are generated: one record needs to be updated with 1 record from run_1 and the other record needs to be inserted. How does the appearance of the log and data files unfold in this scenario? How does the log file keep track?

```
Here's the breakdown:

 * Data specific to Run-1 (1 record)
 * Data specific to Run-2 (1 new record)
 * Data updates/merge: One record from the Run-1 file needs to be merged with the Run-2 file.
```

```
 During Run-1:
    * log file : 00000.json
    * Data file : file_1.parquet (contains 2 records)

 During Run-2:
   * log file : 00001.json, 00002.json (how latest json log file tracks updated data?)
   * Data file : how many files generated? does it generate 2 files one for new records and one for records to be updated?
```

I'm unsure if this is the appropriate forum for this. kindly direct me to the correct one if it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier log file remains as it is. New delta log files point to new parquet file with add action and remove action for older files

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).